What is the default Azure SQL connection pool size?
Our SQL client hit this exception:
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Resource ID : 1. The request limit for the database is 200 and has been reached. See 'https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/azure-sql/database/resource-limits-logical-server' for assistance.

First, it is not a good sign that our application can create over 200 SQL connections. But still, I want to find out where this 200 limit is defined.
I did some research and find the following numbers which I don't quite understand.

Max Pool Size = 100, according to this document.
Max concurrent sessions = 30_000, for premium tier, according to this document

First, I want to know if the request limit mentioned in the error message is related to connection pool or concurrent session at all.
Second, where is that 200 limit defined and can I change it?
Thanks.

have ever got know how to find the optimum setting for this?
